# Manipulate data when a job is running in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a scheduled job in Sql Server 2012. When the job runs every 20 mins, it executes a stored procedure and fills a new table. It takes a lot of time to update the table every time and I don't want an empty table when the job is running.

This is something I'm trying,

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J 
      JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity A 
          ON A.job_id=J.job_id 
      WHERE J.name=N'MyJobName' 
      AND A.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND A.stop_execution_date IS NULL
     )
PRINT 'The job is running!'
ELSE
PRINT 'The job is not running.'
```

So, basically when the job is running, instead of printing, I want to return data from a new table or something. The idea is, I do not want an empty data set even when the job is running.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: And when job running and your table is empty, what do you want ?

Comment: I've tried copying the main table into a temp table. So when the job is running, I am retrieving the data from the temp table and else I am retrieving the data from the main table. But it's not working.

Comment: Show Us your Job @Arpita

Comment: IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
          FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J 
          JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity A 
              ON A.job_id=J.job_id 
          WHERE J.name=N'MyJobName' 
          AND A.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
          AND A.stop_execution_date IS NULL
         )
    select * from TempGetData
ELSE
    select * from GetData